# How do I add custom JSON code to Magento 2?

Tags: content-management-system, magento2, schema.org, structured-data

A company i am working with uses Magento 2 as their CMS.

They would like to add schema.org markup to different pages on their site.

Ideally, I would like to add using JSON. I would create the necessary JSON code and then add it to their site somewhere within the page's head section.

Is it possible to add custom code to different pages within Magento 2? If so, how is this done?

Comment: Do you want to add code for all pages or certain pages?

Comment: it would be just certain pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to add a custom `phtml` template file in the header for all pages and need to check each page types there. So you can add your own custom logic for different pages. Please follow the steps below:

Step 1: Create your custom template file here `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom_codes.phtml`

```
<?php
    $getLayoutHandle = $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName(); // it returns all kind of pages handlers. just check and use by the following ways.
?>
<?php if($getLayoutHandle == 'cms_index_index'): ?>
    <!-- home page scripts here -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($getLayoutHandle == 'catalog_category_view'): ?>
    <!-- product listing page scripts here -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($getLayoutHandle == 'catalog_product_view'): ?>
    <!-- product details page scripts here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Step 2: Add to the above file in the header by using default.xml.
`app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_codes" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom_codes.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi Milan with the code above it looks like the JSON code would be applied to all pages of a certain type.(ie all product pages). Is it possible to modify the code so it is added to specific pages only (for example a specific product page?)

Comment: Yes, It's possible. Try to use this code snippet inside `catalog_product_view`. This snippet returns product id, so you can compare specific product's page there.  Thie snippet `$catalogHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
        $prodId = $catalogHelper->getProduct()->getId();`